# Add a contents page to an excel printout with page numbers showing where each sheet 's page can be found

Tags: vba, excel, pagination

I have a workbook with 40 worksheets and a menu sheet that lists all the sheets. The user chooses which sheets are to be printed and prints them to a PDF document (directly from Excel). All done with `VBA`.

I want the menu sheet to be printed as the first page (ideally not the last page) and for it to show the page number that the first printed page of each sheet can be found.

Bear in mind that some sheets may sometimes print on one page and sometimes on 2 pages, depending on the data that has been loaded.

So part of this solution is finding out how many sheets of paper a worksheet will print onto. Help!

A compromise which I've been considering, is for each sheet to be allocated a number on the menu and for this section number to appear in a cell on each sheet.  When the sheet prints I'd like to print the section number on  all pages used for the sheet, and when sheets print onto multiple pages,  I want a second number that increments when each page of a section is printed,  restarting at 1 when each section starts.

I've used the `workbook_print` event before.  I'm expecting to use the `worksheet_print` event to set up a suitable footer for each sheet or sheet page.

Any guiding thoughts would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: or http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/printed-pages.htm

Comment: Thanks guys, thats a good start. Now how to create a contents page... which I can do now using the links you sent.  I'm still hoping someone might have a class that i can use to do this... Hmmm.. I feel one coming on.  Will post it here as a self answer unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: That's the spirit!  I can't wait to see what you do.  I really like your contents page idea.  Are you using check boxes to choose which sheets to print?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks. GET.DOCUMENT(50)  is definitely the key to solving this problem as it tells you how many pages a sheet will use when printing.  However, how long will excel version 4 macros be supported by Excel?  I've tried to write a VBA function that does the same thing and it is possible, but a bit of a nightmare, and probably unnecessary.  The MS web page here:  [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109976)  states that excel 4 macros will continue to be supported in future version of excel.  (Which is a relief.  I can bin my VBA function).